# Do SQL User-Defined Functions support SELECT clauses?

Tags: google-bigquery

The documentation for SQL-based UDFs is [sparse](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql-udf-structure). I'm wondering if it's possible to write a full-fledged SELECT clause, using the UDF parameters in the query. So in effect, each invocation of the UDF would result in a subquery.

Contrived example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION foo(bar STRING) AS (
SELECT * FROM `example.latest` WHERE thing = bar
);

SELECT foo('abc')
```

BigQuery gives the error "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT; failed to parse CREATE [TEMP] FUNCTION statement" so I assume it's not possible, but would love to get confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT is supported in general but unfortunatelly you cannot reference table(s) in UDF!

See [UDF Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limitations) for more

Comment: Also [star the feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906020) if this is something that you want. Thanks!